# How to specify multiprocessing Manager().Queue() typing in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a function that takes as argument a queue from 'Manager().Queue(1)'. I would like to annotate my function with something like this:

```
def myfunction(queue: ManagerQueue) -> None:
    pass
```

I know I can use Callable but I don't think that it makes much sense.

Is there any way of doing so ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't really distinguish whether you are passing in:

- `multiprocessing.Manager().Queue(1)` or
- `multiprocessing.Manager().Queue`

The first option would give you

```py
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue

def myfunction(queue: Queue) -> None:
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myfunction(multiprocessing.Manager().Queue())
```

The second option

```py
import multiprocessing
from collections import Callable
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue

def myfunction(queue_creator: Callable[[int], Queue]) -> None:
    my_queue = queue_creator(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myfunction(multiprocessing.Manager().Queue)
```

Hopes this answers your question. Let me know if something remains unclear.

Comment: In your example, it seems that Manager().Queue() is the same as multiprocessing,queues ? Is that right ?

Comment: Yes. I was under the assumption you were using the manager of multiprocessing.